# execute a list of commands and store outputs into a list

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, pipe, output

I'm receiving as input a stream of commands:

```
command1
command2
command3
```

From this, I would like to create a file `output.txt` containing:

```
command1 output1
command2 output2
command3 output3
```

Where the `output_i` is the output of `command_i` (each command returns a single integer). I can do that using `parallel` and `paste` successively, but I was wondering whether there is a way to get `output.txt` in a single bash call.

EDIT
with `parallel`, this is how I do it:

```
cat commands.txt | parallel -k > outputs_only.txt
paste commands.txt outputs_only.txt > outputs.txt
```

Comment: Can you show how you'd solve the problem using `parallel`?

Comment: Sure, I updated.

Comment: Do you have commands and outputs in two separate files?

Comment: Yeah I put the outputs in one file, then create a file with both commands and outputs, but I would like to create this last file directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a loop in `bash` with input-redirection on the file containing the commands,

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do 
    echo "$line" "$(eval "$line")"
done < commands.txt > output.txt
```

Or in a *single-line* as

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line" "$(eval "$line")"; done < commands.txt > output.txt
```

---

In case you want to read from `stdin` and not from a file, just *pipe* the stream to the loop,

```
< command-producing-stream > | while read -r line; do echo "$line" "$(eval "$line")"; done > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an equivalent that would allow me to do this without having to create the `commands.txt` file? I actually don't have this file, as I receive `commands.txt` as a stream.